# lsusb failing when I plug in my build light

Tags: usb, lsusb

Just ran into a very strange problem using Ubuntu 14.04. I am running a build light server and the now when I plug in the build light, it flashes every 10 seconds and my program can't access it (hangs when using libusb). I tried running lsusb but got no output at all and can't even terminate using control+c. I've included some debug output here but let me know if there's anything else I can provide that can help.

sudo strace libusb

```
    execve("/usr/bin/lsusb", ["lsusb"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xa7a000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f18169b6000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=108659, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 108659, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f181699b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P:\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92864, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2188384, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f181657f000
mprotect(0x7f1816594000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1816794000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x15000) = 0x7f1816794000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\36\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=100728, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2195784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1816366000
mprotect(0x7f181637e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f181657d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f181657d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1845024, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f181699a000
mmap(NULL, 3953344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1815fa0000
mprotect(0x7f181615c000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f181635b000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bb000) = 0x7f181635b000
mmap(0x7f1816361000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1816361000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0200\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=67600, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2164816, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1815d8f000
mprotect(0x7f1815d9f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1815f9e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xf000) = 0x7f1815f9e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0po\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=141574, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2217264, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1815b71000
mprotect(0x7f1815b8a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1815d89000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f1815d89000
mmap(0x7f1815d8b000, 13616, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1815d8b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0206\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=108480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1816999000
mmap(NULL, 2203688, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1815956000
mprotect(0x7f181596f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1815b6e000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f1815b6e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`G\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=96280, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2191776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f181573e000
mprotect(0x7f1815755000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1815954000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f1815954000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340,\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=38920, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2134040, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1815534000
mprotect(0x7f181553c000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f181573c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7f181573c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@h\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=281552, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1816998000
mmap(NULL, 2377408, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f18152ef000
mprotect(0x7f1815333000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f1815532000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x43000) = 0x7f1815532000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31792, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2129016, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f18150e7000
mprotect(0x7f18150ee000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f18152ed000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f18152ed000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1816997000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1816996000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1816994000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f1816994740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f181635b000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1815d89000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f18152ed000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1815532000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1815954000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f181573c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1815b6e000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1815f9e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f181657d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1816794000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x617000, 8192, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f18169b8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f181699b000, 108659)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f1816994a10)         = 28126
set_robust_list(0x7f1816994a20, 24)     = 0
futex(0x7fff4e3576d0, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 7f1816994740) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f1815b779f0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f1815b81340}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f1815b77a80, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f1815b81340}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xa7a000
brk(0xa9b000)                           = 0xa9b000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7216688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 7216688, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f1814a05000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids", O_RDONLY) = 3
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(3, "#\n#\tList of USB ID's\n#\n#\tMaintai"..., 8192) = 8192
read(3, "1811  PSC 720\n\t1812  OfficeJet P"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "S 802.11n Wireless Adapter\n\t0300"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "o\n0429  Cirrus Logic\n042a  Erics"..., 16384) = 16384
brk(0xabc000)                           = 0xabc000
read(3, "ed Pocket PC 2003\n\t0447  Windows"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, ". Computer Corp.\n\t0100  Keyboard"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "0 Scanner\n\t1702  MP410 Composite"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "Stylus Photo RX640/RX650]\n\t081d "..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "\n\t1003  MP3 Player and Recorder\n"..., 16384) = 16384
brk(0xadd000)                           = 0xadd000
read(3, "7D1102 N150/Surf Micro Wireless "..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "rtner\n\t0010  Graphire\n\t0011  Gra"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "]\n\t00db  FotoShow Zip 250 Driver"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "press Card\n\t0400  UFDC\n\t0401  UF"..., 16384) = 16384
brk(0xafe000)                           = 0xafe000
read(3, "evice\n\t2528  Storage device (8gB"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "sil ISL3886]\n\tee13  SMC2862W-G v"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "Voice Recorder & Camera W-10\n\t02"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, " HPNA Home Phoneline RJ-1\n084d  "..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "C\n\t651b  TravelDrive 2C\n\t651c  T"..., 16384) = 16384
brk(0xb1f000)                           = 0xb1f000
read(3, "istbands Printer\n\t930a  Printer\n"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "a33  PocketPC Sync\n\t0a34  Pocket"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "/485 (Port 3)\n\t2433  SeaPORT+4 ("..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "ter\n\t5501  Mass Storage Device\n\t"..., 16384) = 16384
brk(0xb40000)                           = 0xb40000
read(3, "int Electronic Corp.\n0fb0  Haurt"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "\t1450  UPort 1450 4-Port RS-232/"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "DTV USB-Ter/HAMA USB DVB-T devic"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "001  EdgePort/4 Serial Port\n\t000"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "00 - DVB-T USB warm\n1861  Tech T"..., 16384) = 16384
brk(0xb61000)                           = 0xb61000
read(3, " controller\n\t000e  Genius KB-120"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "t BDA Device\n\t0225  Remote Kit I"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "gital Microscope (SN9C201 + MI13"..., 16384) = 16384
read(3, "43  Slow Blink On Time\n\t044  Slo"..., 16384) = 16384
brk(0xb82000)                           = 0xb82000
read(3, "u SAR\nL 0005  Czech\nL 0006  Dani"..., 16384) = 3236
read(3, "", 13148)                      = 0
read(3, "", 16384)                      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/bus/usb", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 96
close(3)                                = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="JohnsMac", ...}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="JohnsMac", ...}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="JohnsMac", ...}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="JohnsMac", ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/bus/usb/devices", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/udev/udev.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=148, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f18169b5000
read(3, "# see udev(7) for details\n#\n# ud"..., 4096) = 148
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f18169b5000, 4096)            = 0
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 15) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, "\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200d5N\377\177\0\0", 16) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000002}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=28126, groups=00000002}, [12]) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, [1], 4) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
pipe([4, 5])                            = 0
fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0x1 (flags O_WRONLY)
fcntl(5, F_SETFL, O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f1814204000
mprotect(0x7f1814204000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f1814a03fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f1814a049d0, tls=0x7f1814a04700, child_tidptr=0x7f1814a049d0) = 28127
stat("/sys/subsystem", 0x7fff4e357480)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 29 entries */, 32768)    = 800
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26258, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 7, 0) = 0x7f18169af000
close(7)                                = 0
futex(0x7f1816360a70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/usb/devices", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
getdents(7, /* 21 entries */, 32768)    = 608
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 49
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 49
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-4", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 49
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-12", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 50
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 45
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 45
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8.3:1.0", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 65
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.3/1-8.3:1.0/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8.3:1.1", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 65
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.3/1-8.3:1.1/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8.3:1.2", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 65
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.3/1-8.3:1.2/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8.3:1.3", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 65
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.3/1-8.3:1.3/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8.3", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 55
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.3/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-0:1.0", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 53
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-0:1.0/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1:1.0", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 57
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8:1.0", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 57
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-12:1.0", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 59
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-12:1.1", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 59
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.1/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-12:1.2", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 59
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.2/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-0:1.0", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 53
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
readlink("/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-4:1.0", "../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000"..., 1024) = 57
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(7, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(7)                                = 0
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 52 entries */, 32768)    = 1544
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
readlink("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1", 0x7fff4e356820, 1024) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
stat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/uevent", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/uevent", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f18169ae000
read(6, "MAJOR=189\nMINOR=0\nDEVNAME=bus/us"..., 4096) = 124
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f18169ae000, 4096)            = 0
open("/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/busnum", O_RDONLY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f18169ae000
read(6, "1\n", 4096)                    = 2
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f18169ae000, 4096)            = 0
open("/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/devnum", O_RDONLY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f18169ae000
read(6, "1\n", 4096)                    = 2
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f18169ae000, 4096)            = 0
open("/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/speed", O_RDONLY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f18169ae000
read(6, "480\n", 4096)                  = 4
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f18169ae000, 4096)            = 0
open("/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/descriptors", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6,
```

dmesg (this repeats many times)

```
[20697.307364] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.004F: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[20697.307386] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.004F: timeout initializing reports
[20697.307520] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.004F: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Delcom Products Inc. USB IO Controller ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[20697.307600] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 81
[20697.547520] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 82 using xhci_hcd
[20697.569052] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fc5, idProduct=b080
[20697.569054] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[20697.569055] usb 1-1: Product: USB IO Controller 
[20697.569056] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Delcom Products Inc.
[20697.569140] usb 1-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[20707.577760] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0050: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[20707.577783] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0050: timeout initializing reports
[20707.577937] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0050: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Delcom Products Inc. USB IO Controller ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[20707.578030] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 82
[20707.817900] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 83 using xhci_hcd
[20707.839504] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fc5, idProduct=b080
[20707.839508] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[20707.839509] usb 1-1: Product: USB IO Controller 
[20707.839511] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Delcom Products Inc.
[20707.839627] usb 1-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[20717.848097] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0051: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[20717.848141] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0051: timeout initializing reports
[20717.848533] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0051: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Delcom Products Inc. USB IO Controller ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[20717.848769] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 83
[20718.088255] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 84 using xhci_hcd
[20718.110000] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fc5, idProduct=b080
[20718.110009] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[20718.110014] usb 1-1: Product: USB IO Controller 
[20718.110018] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Delcom Products Inc.
[20718.110325] usb 1-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
```